# 2 tables, 3 columns need 1 value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I am trying to get 5 bits of data, 5 of them come from `tbl_playerstats` 
these columns are

```
StatsID 

Score

Kills

Deaths

Rank
```

What im struggling with it that `StatsID` is linked to another table called `tbl_playerdata`
In this table the `PlayerID` is the same as `StatsID` their values are numeric, also in this `tbl_playerdata` is `SoldierName` which is what im am trying to put in place of `StatsID` , end goal being that only these show:

```
SoldierName

Score

Kills

Deaths

Rank
```

My code so far looks like this ( minus database connection details

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT StatsID, Score, Kills, Deaths, Rounds FROM tbl_playerstats Limit 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Soldier: ". $row["StatsID"]. "<p> Score: ". $row["Score"]. "<p> Kills: ". $row["Kills"]. " <p>Deaths: " . $row["Deaths"] . $row["Rounds"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

I have googled and it looks like using a `JOIN` is the way to go, the examples that I have found haven't worked for me, this could be down to not really knowing what this is called I'm trying to do.

Comment: there is no $row["Rounds"] column in this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join both tables using `StatsID` and `PlayerID`

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT tps.*, tpd.* FROM tbl_playerstats tps, tbl_playerdata tpd WHERE tps.StatsID = tpd.PlayerID Limit 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> Soldier: ". $row["SoldierName"]. "<p> Score: ". $row["Score"]. "<p> Kills: ". $row["Kills"]. " <p>Deaths: " . $row["Deaths"] . $row["Rounds"] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if your tbl_playerstats main table then use left join with condition `tps.StatsID  = tpd.StatsID` , hope it will help you

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT tpd.SoldierName,tps.Score,tps.Kills,tps.Deaths,tps.Rank FROM tbl_playerstats tps LEFT JOIN tbl_playerdata tpd on tps.StatsID  = tpd.StatsID Limit 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> SoldierName: ". $row["SoldierName"]. "<p> Score: ". $row["Score"]. "<p> Kills: ". $row["Kills"]. " <p>Deaths: " . $row["Deaths"] . $row["Rank"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

and if you want to same data then use innner join

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT tpd.SoldierName,tps.Score,tps.Kills,tps.Deaths,tps.Rank FROM tbl_playerstats tps, tbl_playerdata tpd WHERE tps.StatsID = tpd.PlayerID Limit 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> SoldierName: ". $row["SoldierName"]. "<p> Score: ". $row["Score"]. "<p> Kills: ". $row["Kills"]. " <p>Deaths: " . $row["Deaths"] . $row["Rank"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

if you face any problem then inform me. i will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hi as your questions is not much clear and also the output is also not much cleared, what  you want?
anyway, you can join two tables to get the common columns from those tables like below.

suppose **table-1** is player have 5 columns

```
stats

score

kill

death

rank
```

and another **tabel 2** is playerData having these columns

```
playerId

playerName 

playerEmail

and so on...!!
```

and you want whole data of table 1 along with the playerEmail, and statId and Playerid is common. then use this query

```
select p.stats, p.score, p.kill, p.death, p.rank, d.playerEmail
from Player p 
inner join playerData d
on p.statid = d.playerid.
```